# Is there a good summary of the different discipline philosophies for pre-school and school aged childern

Tags: pre-schooler, discipline, primary-schooler

Is there a good website or book that describes and compares the current leading approaches to disciplining pre-school and school aged children.  I realize that there are numerous opinions on the best approach to discipline for children and that they likely have different strengths and weaknesses.

I am looking for a site or book that will allow me to learn about and evaluate the current leading schools of thought.

Comment: Trouble is, any single author is likely to have their own axe to grind, so you are not likely to get a good understanding from just one book. Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenting_styles has some introductory information and pointers to more details, but I don't know how comprehensive it is.

Comment: It might be unlikely to find a *single* book that covers the different methods unless it's specifically comparing opposing views. You may get a better response by instead asking *us* what some of the leading methodologies are, and where you can find out more about them. I'm sure you'll have to read more than one source, anyway.

Answer (score 6):

[BabyCenter's "What's Your Discipline Style?"](http://www.babycenter.com/big-story-your-discipline-style) includes a downloadable chart of different discipline philosophies (Positive Discipline, Gentle Discipline, Boundary-Based Discipline, Emotion-Coaching, and Behavior-Modification) with a summary of each one's primary emphasis, techniques, and an example of how it works. At the end of each column are the names of 1-3 books on that particular school of thought so you can learn more.

Here's another article that may broaden your scope: ["How They Do It: An Overview of Child Rearing around the World."](http://www.babble.com/baby/child-rearing-around-world/) It gives a brief overview of discipline beliefs and strategies in China, Japan, India, Egypt and Africa, as well as Native American, Latino and European cultures. Here are some excerpts.

China

> Discipline practices in China are based on ancient Confucian ethics
>   and the belief that infants arrive from the gods with an inherently
>   good nature that is to be respected.

India

> Indian moms lovingly massage their babies daily and carry them close
>   to their bodies. Co-sleeping during the early years is another
>   characteristic of the close mother-infant relationship.... [However],
>   discipline is often strict and children are taught to obey their
>   parents.

Africa

> In [Mali, Nigeria, Namibia, Zambia, and Malawi], not only are children
>   highly valued, but being childless is considered the worst fate that
>   can befall a man and a woman. The entire community considers it their
>   responsibility to see that each child, a “gift of God,” is raised
>   appropriately. Elders transmit their cultural values and teach the
>   young, and discipline centers around the values that children are
>   expected to learn.